# How do you access the recovery mode of Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

Microsoft disabled the recovery mode key (F8) and replaced it with some automatic detection algorithms.

These detection algorithms begin every couple of times you boot up but it doesn't complete the boot process. I can get that far. However, I can not get to any menus.

Is there anything else I could try before I reformat the drive and try again?

Comment: You act like that is Windows 8's fault.  Something happen to your installation, a normal user, won't have to wait 2 hours.

Comment: It was my fault that the machine was borked, because I used the command line to disable `DEP`. Doing that on Win8 results in a broken (non-booting system).  Lesson learned: Don't DO that. ;-)

Comment: So by recovery mode, you probably mean `safe mode`, and not the Recovery Console included in older versions of Windows. Which loads even less than `safe mode`.

Comment: Mostly I just want Windows to offer me some repair choices.  Safe Mode actually offers very little in terms of recovery or repair options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Windows 8, the `Shift+F8` keyboard shortcut at boot should open up recovery mode.

Answer (score 2):

`Shift+F8` sir. Not just `F8`. Windows 8 is fancy :)